# Lower bound on average shortest path in graphs

Tags: graph-theory, geodesic, random-graphs

I am looking for information on the **lower bound of the average [shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)) in a connected undirected graph**, given the number $n$ of vertices and number $k$ of edges in the graph.

I would like to know how this relates to the average shortest path in random graphs with the same $n$ and $k$.

"Practical" results based on approximations and heuristics are also useful.

---

The average shortest path is defined as 
$$
L = \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i < j} s_{ij},
$$
where $s_{ij}$ is the smallest number of edges we need to traverse to move from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ in the graph.  I.e., take the length of the shortest path between all vertex pairs and average them.